# How to detect which timeout timeout occurred?

Tags: java, okhttp

I have set up OkHTTP in the following way:

```
this.okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
```

And I use the following snippet to send the request

```
    try (Response response = this.okHttpClient.newCall(nativeRequest).execute()) {
        // response is awailable here
    }
```

So far so good.

`execute()` method may throw `IOException`. Now I need to find out from the IOException, what kind of timeout occurred. Whether it was `connectTimeout`, `writeTimeout` or `readTimeout`.

Does anyone know how to do that? Or is there any other library can give me this kind of information?

Comment: hmm, I found it: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3318